# Java home folder is different for sudo user on AWS

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2, sudo, java-11

I have read many instructions on the problem, but I cannot get the sudo user (the normal ec2-user works fine) to use the proper JAVA_HOME folder.

I have tried:
set JAVA_HOME in .bash of /root and default user
set JAVA_HOME in etc/bashrc
set Default keep_env += JAVA_HOME in etc/sudoers

I use to set JAVA_HOME:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11"

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and I tried:

```
############set java home 
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11" 
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

restarted the instance after all these changes

still sudo java -version keeps pointing to the old java location (1.8 and i need 11)

what am I missing?

Regards,

Rick

Comment: do you not need to export your path as well?

Comment: I tried 
```
############set java home
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11"
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```
on /etc/profile and root/.bashrc, but didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

After making changes to your .bash file, source it using command

```
source .bash
```

and try to check the version.

Comment: hi thanks for your command. I did that, as wel as . .bash as well as full restart of instance. I just doesn't pick up.

Comment: can you try to update your .bash_profile too and source it as well, since you are trying to set the environment variable.